# Deploying a Ruby On Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

Once I've finished my Ruby On Rails app, I want to deploy it on a server.

What steps should I do?
Should I generate a file as for example a .war in Java?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) is the most popular way to deploy Ruby On Rails.  Enjoy [this screencast](http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/basic-deployment-with-capistrano/).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this link.You will get a clear idea about Ruby On Rails app deploy

http://rubyonrails.org/deploy

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying to regular server (non cloud) you can use the capistrano gem [here's a good screencast on how to](http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/basic-deployment-with-capistrano/). If you want a cloud based service you can't beat [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Ideal and Easy way - you need to you best practices like

1. Version control with Git
2. Heroku Setup (which is free) (You can think for engine yard)

Here is the few links

[Version control with Git](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning.html#sec-version_control)

[Deploying with Heroku](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning.html#sec-deploying)

[Link from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)

Please let me know if you need more information on this.